# Tkinter: How to make a button center itself?

Tags: python, tkinter, centering

I'm making a program in Python and I want to go with a layout that is a bunch of buttons in the center. How do I make a button center itself using pack()?

Comment: Have you tried anything, if so include any code noting where you are stuck.

Comment: This related question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5114487/945456

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To center horizontally this should be enough

```
button.pack(side=TOP)
```

But to center horizontally and vertically you could use nested frames. Check the following script:

```py
import tkinter as tk

#%% Frames
frameA = tk.Frame(background="#c8c8c8")
frameB = tk.Frame(width=200, height = 200, background="#646464")
# Nested Frame. framebb is created within frameB without width or height
framebb = tk.Frame(frameB, background="#646464")
frameC = tk.Frame(width=100, height = 100, background="bisque")

frameA.pack(side='top', fill=None)
frameB.pack(side='top')
# expand is the key parameter to center the framebb within frameB
framebb.pack(expand=True)
frameC.pack(side='bottom')

#frameA.pack_propagate(False)
frameB.pack_propagate(False)
frameC.pack_propagate(False)

#%% Buttons and Labels
tk.Label(frameA, text = "Text within the frame A").pack()

a = tk.Button(framebb, text = "A").pack()
b = tk.Button(framebb, text = "B").pack()
c = tk.Button(framebb, text = "C").pack()
d = tk.Button(frameC, text = "D").pack()
e = tk.Button(frameC, text = "E").pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: script_with_center_buttons]

Another approach could be using the `.grid()` method

```
button.grid(row=1,col=0)
```

the values of `row=1,col=0` depend of the position of the other widget in your window

or you can use `.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)`

```
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

Notice that the parameter `anchor` is referencing the a relative position to the object (in this case button). `anchor` is not referencing to a position in the window. You could think that the button is a ship that has several anchors so you should choose a coordinate and which anchor you want to fix in that coordinate.

Example using `.place()`:

```py
from tkinter import *  # Use this if use python 3.xx
#from Tkinter import *   # Use this if use python 2.xx
a = Button(text="Center Button")
b = Button(text="Top Left Button")
c = Button(text="Bottom Right Button")

# You can use the strings the referencing the relative position on the button
# strings = n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, c or center
# Or you can use the constants of tkinter
# N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW, CENTER
a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
b.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, anchor=NW)
c.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor=SE)
mainloop()
```

[image: tk window]

Comment: Thanks! One question though: If I use `anchor=CENTER` on every button will they all overlap each other?

Comment: Yes. They'll overlap each others. But you can changes the relatives coord for that doesn't happen. Anchor indicate the reference point don't the position.

Comment: can you add examples using pack and grid too please?

Comment: Note that for the grid manager you may end up having to use the `columnspan` or `rowspan` options (see here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), and maybe even the `Grid.columnconfigure` and `Grid.rowconfigure` methods to change the weights from 0 to 1 (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591294/how-to-create-a-self-resizing-grid-of-buttons-in-tkinter/). In either case, showing examples of what you've done above using the other Geometry managers you mentioned too would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for Answering.It was helpful,

Comment: What about centering horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

this is slightly old now, you have to do this:

```
import tkinter as tk #you can do 'from tkinter import *', any is fine
btn = tk.Button(text = "Centered Button")
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```